# Kafka connect plugin which runs python code

Tags: python, java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I don't have expirience with java language, but I'd like to use Kafka Connect for integrations. I'm looking for solution to wrap python code using kafka connect plugin and use it within kafka connect cluster.
First of all I want to figure it out is it possible and what barriers might be on the go.

I explored some example of hello-world kafka plugins and explained the main concept of plugin structure, it starts separate thread which do something.
I think sinc connector might be implemented as python script which will be called through java thread (like regular system call) with provided argument with massage. What java lib should I use to it?
The source connector should works similar, but it need to catch the output of system call, I think it might be implemented like it done in airflow xcoms (parse last line of output as json string), and I also didn't find right way for that, can you suggest something?
One more question in my mind it's about how to manage python's vienvs from java thread?
Or maybe you know already implemented kafka connect plugins for system cli calls?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect has plugin architecture and you have to configure the plugin path as part of Kafka configuration. It will only load Java classes from plugin path. There are multiple Kafka connect plugins are available, you can reuse them as per your need for integration. You don't need to build your own connector always.

Python is not a supported language  to develop a custom Kafka connect plugin.

Comment: yep, I understand the main concept of kafka connect, and know that python is not supported. I want to build "universal" kafka connect wrapper to run python code.

Comment: @Philipp Then you need to wrap Python code in a JVM language (it does not need to "be Java". You can write plugins in Groovy, Scala, Kotlin, Clojure, etc. But to call python code, you need to run a subprocess  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yep subprocesses it looks like what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python, then do that. I.e. Use Airflow to consume some topic, then produce to another topic. Or, use solutions like Faust / Fluvii Python frameworks, or look into solutions like PySpark, PyFlink, Beam, etc.

Kafka Connect is just one tool. It unfortunately requires Java. This does not prevent you from "pre-processing" the data other ways before a Connector reads any data.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the answer, I thought about pros which I have with kafka connect from the box like high availability, fault tolerance, scalability. With pure python I have to do it my self. I consider this idea of kafka connector like wrapper to have this features.

Comment: It's not exactly "do yourself" if you use something like Kubernetes or Nomad to run those Python tasks.

Comment: There are other, no-code solutions like NiFi, Benthos, [Conduit](https://conduit.io/docs/features/pipeline-semantics), LogStash, https://vector.dev. Telegraf